# (How) can a Spring <form: tag handle multiple Model Attributes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

After reading related questions, such as:

[Spring MVC form handling form multiple pojos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390951/spring-mvc-form-handling-form-multiple-pojos)

[Spring MVC: Having multiple @ModelAttribute in form handling action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244320/spring-mvc-having-multiple-modelattribute-in-form-handling-action)

I still wonder how could a Spring MVC <form: tag handle multiple modelAttributes. In the answers to the questions above, they either use JSON ( Why?) or use some tricks in the name of the raw input HTML tags.
Could somebody post a minimal, working example here ( two Pojos, a Controller and a view)?

Comment: You can only have a single model attribute. If you want multiple you need to wrap those in another single attribute. Or stop using the form tags, write a regular HTML form and deduct the `name` from the model attributes you want to use. Although you will loose the fact that a form is pre-filled with the values from the model attribute.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you post this as an answer, please? With a minimal, working example? Thank you!

Comment: That is already in one of the questions you refer to.

Comment: @M.Deinum which one do you mean? I cannot get working neither of them!